# GitHub Actions - Open/Write to two groups in paralell

Tags: github-actions

I'm creating a GitHub action, where I have two loops running in parallel, writing to the console.

Example:

```js
async function loop(name) {
  core.startGroup(name);
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    core.info(`[INFO] {${name}}: ${i} { type = log, task = ${name} }`);
    await delay(1000); // delay = promise that wraps setTimeout
  }
  core.endGroup();
}

loop('a');
loop('b');
```

I expect each loop to write to its respective group

[image]

Instead, I see this in the job logs

[image]

Which isn't a surprise since `loop('b')` overrides the group opening.

Is there a way to write output to a specific group, even when running in parallel?

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't reproduce your result using `github-script`, result [here](https://github.com/JJ/d-a-9/runs/1207984383?check_suite_focus=true). Maybe it's fixed in that version. Here's the GH action I used:

```yaml
name: "Checks loop"
on: [push]

jobs:
  check_group_loop:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Use Node.js
        uses: actions/github-script@v3
        with:
          github-token: ${{secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN}}
          script: |
              function loop(name) {
                  core.startGroup(name);
                  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                      core.info("[INFO] " + name + ": " + i );
                 }
                 core.endGroup();
              }

              loop('a');
              loop('b');
```

Maybe you can show the whole action so that we can check?
Anyway, the problem seems to be the calls are asynchronous, so instead of using start/end, could you [wrap loggging in a group](https://github.com/actions/toolkit/tree/main/packages/core#logging)

Comment: the code snippet that I've posted was a bit misleading :/ updated it now. it's an async function that sleeps for 1sec every loop iteration. sorry about that

Comment: @areller Then probably wrapping is the solution anyway

Comment: I tried it already, it does the same thing. Looking at the implementation of `group`, it just calls `startGroup`, calls the function and then calls `endGroup`

Comment: Then maybe change tack and give @github-script a chance?